# can method area of JVM be garbage collected?

Tags: java, jvm

so I was reading the JVM specification, and encountered the following section:

> Although the method area is logically part of the heap, simple implementations may choose not to either garbage collect or compact it.

I am not sure that I get that, is this saying that the text segments in JVM could be garbage collected ? how should I understand that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am not sure that I get that, is this saying that the text segments in JVM could be garbage collected ?

This is not typically referring to "text" (words) or to the "text segment" in the Unix/Linux sense.  It is referring to the dynamically allocated regions of memory that contains a method's bytecode and/or JIT compiled native code.  It is saying that *those* memory segments *could* be garbage collected ... depending on the JVM implementation, etcetera ... but this is NOT a requirement of the JVM specification.

---

In a JVM implementation where Java bytecodes are compiled to native code and linked into an executable image *ahead of time*, you will have "text segments", and those text segments *won't* be subject to garbage collection.  (They can't be, because they are read only, and possibly shared with other instances of the application executing at the same time.)

Comment: exactly! I was wondering how they implement gc to recollect those method are, that must be a totally different gc which is used to collect data memory.

Comment: Well, when the "method area" is dynamically allocated, the JVM typically puts it in the PermGen heap.  This is still subject to garbage collection in a typical modern JVM.  However, unless you are doing clever things with classloaders, the "method area" objects will remain reachable for the entire lifetime of the application, and hence won't ever be collected.

Answer (score 2):

When a method executes, local variables live on the stack.

It is conceivable that The JVM may chose to not collect local variables and re-use the same memory for the next execution of the method. Such a choice would only be sane in single-threaded runtime environments.

Comment: sorry, I am still not quite get it: are you talking about the frame could be reused ?  what I am concerned is the method area 'text segment' that could be GCed.

Comment: I don't think the quoted sentence in the Question is referring to stack frames at all.  The "method area" I think refers to the region of application memory where the method **code** resides.

Comment: @StephenC I meant stack. I thought stack. But I wrote heap.